# SurveyMonkey create_collector throwing error

Tags: surveymonkey

I am trying to test a call to the Survey Monkey API endpoint create_collector, but I always get this error, even on their API Console page:

{
  "status": 3,
  "errmsg": "additional properties not defined by 'properties' are not allowed in field '_data'"
}

Even if I type nothing into the API Console and hit "Try It", I still get this error.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It appears the problem is solely with their API Console test page, shame on them.  I can write code against the API endpoint and it works fine.

Comment: I've forwarded this internally but you might want to email api-support@surveymonkey.com about this too. It does look like something wrong on the SurveyMonkey side.

Comment: Done, I emailed the address.  Thanks.